# Does Oracle PL/SQL have a standard ASSERT routine?

Tags: oracle, error-handling

I'd like to use an ASSERT routine functionally similar to the one found in other languages, i.e. a construct (be it a procedure, syntax...)

```
ASSERT( <condition>, <msg>)
```

such that when the `<condition>` passed in the first argument is false an exception is raised with the specified `<msg>` descriptive message.

I know this is trivial to do by hand but **I'm asking if there's a standard one** provided with the DBMS.

Having to write my own one or import one from 3rdy-party packages would be impractical, since I'd need it to be completely portable and transparent to every project I'm working on.

Comment: Nope, you will have to build your own. Impracticality has a low threshold nowadays :)

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a built-in assertion procedure in SQL or PL/SQL, so you will have to write your own.

There are two ways of going about this. You can either manually raise an exception, as discussed in [this Oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o33plsql-l1-101540.html), or you can write a wrapper for the `raise_application_error` procedure, which is documented in the [Oracle exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm) section of the documentation.

I'll add that exceptions were designed for this kind of scenario, so you'd be better off taking your programmer hat off for a second & using your DBA hat :)

Answer (score 8):

The built in [DBMS_ASSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#ARPLS231) package is a narrowly scoped version of what you are looking for. For other asserts Phil is correct, you will have to build your own.  Here is a simple demonstration of the second option in Phil's answer<sup>+1</sup>:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000
Declare

   Procedure Assert (pCondition In Number, pMessage In Varchar2) Is
   Begin
      If (pCondition = 1) Then
         Return; 
      End If;
      Raise_Application_Error(-20001, pMessage);
   End Assert;

Begin
   DBMS_Output.Put_Line('Start');

   Assert(Case When 1+1=2 Then 1 Else 0 End,'Something is wrong 1.');
   Assert(Case When 1+1=9 Then 1 Else 0 End,'Something is wrong 2.');

   DBMS_Output.Put_Line('End');
End;
/
```

Comment: DBMS_ASSERT is targeted at SQL parsing, hence me not mentioning it.

Comment: @Phil and that's why I said narrowly scoped.  Perhaps that should be extremely narrowly scoped. :)